# Formula for memory alignment

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

While browsing through some kernel code, I found a formula for memory alignment as

> aligned = ((operand + (alignment - 1)) & ~(alignment - 1))

So then I even write a program for this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    long long operand;
    long long alignment;
    if(argv[1]) {
        operand = atol(argv[1]);
    } else {
        printf("Enter value to be aligned!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if(argv[2]) {
        alignment = strtol(argv[2],NULL,16);
    } else {
        printf("\nDefaulting to 1MB alignment\n");
        alignment = 0x100000;
    }
    long long aligned = ((operand + (alignment - 1)) & ~(alignment - 1));
    printf("Aligned memory is: 0x%.8llx [Hex] <--> %lld\n",aligned,aligned);
    return 0;
}
```

But I don't get this logic at all. How does this work?

Comment: Write it out of paper, in *binary*. Both the unaligned and the aligned values. Perform the operations *on paper* one by one to see the results of each part of the expression, and puzzle it all together. All done with the binary values of course.

Comment: Just for sake of precision it have to be clarified that the alignment boundaries **must be powers of 2**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically, the formula increase an integer `operand` (address) to a next address aligned to the `alignment`.

The expression

```
aligned = ((operand + (alignment - 1)) & ~(alignment - 1))
```

is basically the same as a bit easier to understand formula:

```
aligned = int((operand + (alignment - 1)) / alignment) * alignment
```

For example, having operand (address) 102 and alignment 10 we get:

```
aligned = int((102 + 9) / 10) * 10
aligned = int(111 / 10) * 10
aligned = 11 * 10
aligned = 110
```

First we add to the address `9` and get `111`. Then, since our alignment is 10, basically we zero out the last digit, i.e. `111 / 10 * 10 = 110`

Please note, that for each power of 10 alignment (i.e. 10, 100, 1000 etc) we basically zeroing out last digits.

On most CPUs, division and multiplication operations take much more time than bitwise operations, so let us get back to the original formula:

```
aligned = ((operand + (alignment - 1)) & ~(alignment - 1))
```

The second part of the formula makes sense only when alignment is a power of 2. For example:

```
... & ~(2 - 1) will zero last bit of address.
... & ~(64 - 1) will zero last 5 bits of address.
etc
```

Just like with zeroing out last few digits  of an address for power of 10 alignments, we zeroing out last few bits for power of 2 alignments.

Hope it does make sense for you now.